# send bulk emails from mandril, sendgrid or any api php code?

Tags: javascript, php

From single text box I am trying to send multiple emails using comma separator, but I cannot send the mails to multiple emails through Mandrill API or Sendgrid API using PHP.

```
$message->to = array(array("email" => $emails);

// How to create multiple array which takeenter code heres multiple emails values from single text box.
if(isset($_POST['to_email'])) {
  $t = $_POST['to_email'];
}

$emails1 = preg_split('/[,;\n]/', $t);

foreach ($emails1  as $emails) {
  echo $emails;
}

echo $len = count($emails);
```

I am not able create array for multiple mails which is sending only one email at a time.

Comment: looking forward for answers tank you

Comment: Why cant you send multiple emails? You havent explained that at all

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formate to send multiple emails.

```
 $expload_array=explode(",",$t);

    foreach ($expload_array  as $key=>$value) {

    sendmail($value);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mandril is not for bulk email sending, mandril is use for personalized email sending. to send bulk email you can use mailchimp . for more difference between mandrill and mailchimp visit this link http://kb.mailchimp.com/mandrill/about-transactional-email